# Sequentially calculate RMSE for each row, each time using the next row (Pandas)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have  dataframe of y_true values and y_predicted values.

I would need to sequently calculate RMSE for each row, each time using the next row. Could describe it something like `row+1`. After that, store the result in new column `RMSE`.

Here is the dataframe. The code would take first row of `y_true = 105, y_pred = 195` and calculate RMSE (I use `from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error`) which would be 90.0 and put it in new column.

After that we take the first row and the next one which would be `y_true = [105, 297], y_pred = [195,337]` and calculate the error again, the result would be 69.6. And do this for the whole dataframe.
Next time `y_true = [105, 297, 262], y_pred = [195,337, 804]` and so on. I assume that this could be done with a loop.

```
   ID  y_true  y_pred
0   1     105     195
1   2     297     337
2   3     262     804
3   4     206     708
4   5     226     705
5   6     309     463
6   7     210     676
7   8     124     573
```

The result should be:

```
   ID  y_true  y_pred    RMSE
0   1     105     195   90.00
1   2     297     337   69.60
2   3     262     804  318.04
3   4     206     708  372.64
4   5     226     705  396.20
5   6     309     463  367.11
6   7     210     676  382.00
7   8     124     573  391.00
```

Currently the code calculates the RMSE

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
import numpy as np

dataframe = pd.read_excel(r'S:\...\df.xlsx')

y_true = dataframe['y_true']
y_pred = dataframe['y_pred']

rmse = mean_squared_error(y_true, y_pred, squared=False)
print(rmse)
```

But the question is how to calculate it for rows, each time taking the next one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your data frame is not too huge, you can use a list comprehension:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'y_true':[105,297,262,206],
'y_pred':[195,337,804,708]})

df['RMSE'] = [mean_squared_error(df.y_true[:(i+1)],
df.y_pred[:(i+1)], squared=False) for i in range(df.shape[0])]

   y_true  y_pred        RMSE
0     105     195   90.000000
1     297     337   69.641941
2     262     804  318.048214
3     206     708  372.648628
```

Or based on how RMSE is calculated,  you want the square root of the incremental mean of squared error, so this gives squared error:

```
(df.y_true - df.y_pred)**2)
```

This gives incremental mean of the above:

```
(df.y_true - df.y_pred)**2).expanding().mean()
```

This adds the square root, which u can see is the same as above:

```
df['RMSE'] = np.sqrt(((df.y_true - df.y_pred)**2).expanding().mean())

   y_true  y_pred        RMSE
0     105     195   90.000000
1     297     337   69.641941
2     262     804  318.048214
3     206     708  372.648628
```

Comment: Great, this works smoothly! And how could I do the same with RMSE%, calculated like  rmse% = (df['RMSE']/ (np.mean(df['y_true'])))*100 ? I tried like this df['RMSE%'] = [((df.RMSE[:(i+1)] / (np.mean(df.y_true[:(i+1)])))*100) for i in range(df.shape[0])]

but somehting is now working

Comment: `df['RMSE'] / df['y_true'].expanding().mean()` if i get you correct

Comment: That works great! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Another way:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
df = pd.read_excel('test.xls')

df["RMSE"] = df.apply(lambda x: mean_squared_error(df.loc[:x.name, 'y_true'].tolist(), df.loc[:x.name, 'y_pred'].tolist(), squared=False), axis = 1)
print(df)
```